# Execute command when connected to a specified ip

Tags: bash, shell, ip, cron, wifi

I want to create a script that execute a command when wlan0 if connected to a specific ip. If connected to a different ip, launch a different command (I have a static ip)
I want to avoid launching this script in public wifi.

I hope you guys understand. English is not my main langage

Comment: Welcome new user. Your english is fine. You just need to read the [ask] and the [help]. We helping with **your** programming problems, but we can't help you to fix **your** code without seeing it. So, [edit] your question and show us what do you already tried. The _I want_ is not an question.

Comment: You can start building some usefull code based on the output of `ifconfig wlan0 |grep -Pwo 'inet \K([0-9]+[.]?)+'`

Answer (score 0):

> Run this script in script in system startup

```
cal()
{
a=$(ip addr | grep "wlan0" | sed '1d' |awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)...$/\1/')
echo $a
b=10.98.35.96
if [ $b = $a ]
then
echo same
#give command
kill -9 $$
else
echo notsame
sleep 3
cal
fi
}

cal
```